past tense vs present
Why in this sentence "called" has been used instead of "call"? (I think it should be "call")

Someone close to you will try to tell you what to do, but it’s time you called the shots, so don’t be afraid to make your own decisions.


Cambridge Dictionary defines it's time.

We can use the expression it’s time + subject + past verb form to refer to the present moment:


Gosh! It’s almost midnight. It’s time we went home.

The OP’s example means the time has come  for you to call the shots.

This particular past tense usage probably seems a bit peculiar to many non-native Anglophones. Many of the results from a Google Books search for it's time you go home are either teaching books (flagging up the error) or have author's names that don't look very Anglophonic. But we do also use the infinitive in such contexts - with a small adjustment to the associated syntax... It's time for you to go home.

Thanks, @FumbleFingers. It's time for you to go home is the most common form I've encountered and used.  Is that also your experience?

Historically, the shorter version was always much more common in informal contexts (that usage chart specifically selects utterances starting with abbreviated It's [time you went], which will mostly be informal / conversational). But the construction itself is unusual / idiomatic, and as the number of non-native users of English keeps rising, such usages are tending to be discarded in favour of more "accessible" phrasing.
